# Battery turned into X after Yosemite

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, battery

After I installed Yosemite on my MacBook Air, the battery icon is just an X.

I have tried restarting the computer, and turning off the computer, then back on, but nothing is happening! Even the charger won't recognize that it is plugged in. This Mac is less than two years old, the battery should be fine.

Comment: how do you turn the battery off and back on?

Comment: So - I'm curious what your System Profiler shows for the battery health? Could you post that as a comment to my answer? (like charge remaining, cycle count and the voltage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found out how to fix the battery. You need to power off the computer, hold *Shift+Control+Option+Power (at the same time)* for a couple of seconds, then turn the computer back on. When you do that, the X should be gone! :)

Answer (score 7):

There is a circuit board on the battery itself that reports its presence and status to the OS X.

In OS X, there is a piece of hardware run by firmware called System Management Controller (SMC) that takes that information and processes it. Sometimes, the SMC gets confused and needs to be reset following [instructions from Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295).

You can also look up your Battery information in the About This Mac, to see what it says.

#### What could cause the display of the X?

The circuit mounted on the battery itself could have malfunctioned. Normally, it will reserve a minimum charge for itself and not allow the battery to drain beyond that point. But, if the battery was drained to the levels that the built-in circuit can no longer function, it will not report the status and ask to be charged. If you were installing Yosemite, you should have gotten a warning that you are on battery. If ignored, the battery could have been drained completely.

So what can you do other than SMC reset or bringing it in for repair? You can try the coconut app to see if it does something. https://www.coconut-flavour.com/coconutbattery/

Answer (score 5):

The hardware that reads the battery health is independent of the OS running so it's just a coincidence that the X appeared with the update. I would get on the phone with AppleCare (or on the web or in a store) and see if they can run some remote diagnostics and tell you what precisely is happening with the battery.

You can also get many details from System Information:

[image: System Information - Power]

However, these snapshot values aren't as good as the tools and manufacturing data that Apple has on specific batteries, models and usage patterns. Basically, once you have the X - the battery will need to be replaced sooner rather than later whether it's two months old or two years old.

Answer (score -3):

i did it by banging my laptop with my hand , it worked seriously , trust me.